# Search XPath in PHP DOMXPath with Query function

Tags: php, xpath, domdocument, domxpath

I have an DOMXPath object, that I created from a DOMDocument, that is this amazon website:

> [https://amazon.com/gp/aw/d/B0839N79CS](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0839N79CS)

I am trying to use some XPaths that work on my Google Chrome, but when I try them on the DOMXPath they doesn't seem to be working.

Here is the example:

```
    $dom = new \DOMDocument();
    $dom->loadHTML($html);//HTML is amazon url
    $html_document= new \DOMXPath($dom);    
    $html_document->query('//*[@id="dp"]//*[@id="productTitle"]/text()');
```

If you check that XPath on Google Chrome inspector, you will see that it works and it gives you the product title. If I only put "//*[@id="productTitle"]/text()" it works, but the thing is I need to know why the other way does not work as sometimes I need that kind of XPath.

Thank you

Comment: Some web sites use javascript when they load to display some content.  It's worth saving `$html` that you use in your DOMDocument and see if that has the same structure as the online version.

Comment: This is not the case, as if I use "//*[@id="productTitle"]/text()" works, but if I use "//*[@id="dp"]//*[@id="productTitle"]/text()" does not work. But in google chrome it works both, and both get the same item that is in the same place